# Posting PROJ question on Stack Overflow and not GIS SE

Tags: discussion, scope, cross-posts

Recently, I posted this question to Stack Overflow:

[How to find a particular coordinate on a Sentinel image using proj:transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017863/how-to-find-a-particular-coordinate-on-a-sentinel-image-using-projtransform)

Was I right to post it there, or would GIS SE be a better fit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question you cite involves [PROJ](https://proj.org/), and:

> PROJ is a generic coordinate transformation software that transforms
> geospatial coordinates from one coordinate reference system (CRS) to
> another.

it is highly on-topic for GIS SE and, I think, less likely to attract suitable expertise to answer it at Stack Overflow.

I recommend that you delete it from there, and re-ask it here instead.  It would become our [500th question about PROJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proj).